# EnumDisplayDevices vs EnumDisplayMonitors

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, screens

I have noticed that [`EnumDisplayDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx) report different information on which monitor is attached to which port.

For example, i have 4 monitors attached to my graphics card. 3 of them are 1920x1080 and one of them is 1280x768.

The information i get from `EnumDisplayMonitors` is:

```
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY1
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY2
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY3
1280 768 \\.\DISPLAY4
```

and the one from `EnumDisplayDevices` is:

```
1280 768 \\.\DISPLAY1
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY2
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY3
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY4
```

Also i noticed that the order in `EnumDisplayDevices` is sometimes shuffled, so it could also be:

```
1280 768 \\.\DISPLAY1
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY4
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY2
1920 1080 \\.\DISPLAY3
```

Anyways, which one is the correct one?

I am looking for this because i want to read the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) data from the correct monitor.

Comment: Monitors can be disabled and remapped by the control panel Display applet.  With EnumDisplayDevices you get the "raw" view, EnumDisplayMonitors gives you the mapped view.  So they are both correct, you'd normally only care about EnumDisplayMonitors.

Comment: @HansPassant: interesting. How can they be remapped? Cause it seems the numbering in the display applet always corresponds to the information from EnumDisplayMonitors.

Comment: Depends on the Windows version, but you for example have an option to arbitrarily make one of the monitors your "primary" monitor.  Looks like you used it.

Comment: yes, i did that, but that doesn't seem to change the order or the numbering of neither EnumDisplayMonitor nor EnumDisplayDevices.